# Run screen from Perl

Tags: java, linux, perl, bash, gnu-screen

I have a Jar file that I would like to run through screen, although when I try to open the Perl script everything seems to be working fine, although when I do `top` I do not see the process in the list, it works just fine if I copy-paste the command into the SSH session...

This is the code I'm using:
start.pl

`# !/usr/local/bin/perl

system("cd /var/server/; screen java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar jarfile.jar > /dev/null 2>&1 &");`

Can someone point out why this is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that screen is trying to grab hold of the terminal, which isn't possible given the context of the `system` command.  The easiest solution is to start the screen session in detached mode by adding the `-d -m` options:

```
# !/usr/local/bin/perl
system("cd /var/server/; screen -d -m java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar jarfile.jar > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```